# How do I force the eclipse Outline View to request a new ContentOutlinePage?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an editor which can supply two different ContentOutlinePages to the outline, depending on the user's choice.

However, when I change the ContentOutlinePage to be displayed, I have to close and reopen the Outline View to see any changes. I understand that the Outline View requests a new ContentOutlinePage when the editor is activated, but is there a way to force it to request a new page at any other time?

I tried just calling

```
activePage.activate(editor);
```

where activePage is the active workbench page and editor ist the editor that is currently being displayed, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than have two content pages you could have one page that can show both of your outlines. To do this you cannot extend the normal `ContentOutlinePage`, instead you need a class like this:

```java
public class MyContentOutlinePage extends Page 
   implements IContentOutlinePage, ISelectionChangedListener
```

The amount of code in the standard `ContentOutlinePage` is quite small so it is not much extra work to implement a page which meets your needs.

Update:
You would have one top level control containing the SashForm and TreeViewer and always return the top control in `getControl()`. You would hide either the SashForm or TreeViewer depending on which you want to show.

The top level control could be something like `PageBook` or a `Composite` using `StackLayout`.

Comment: But I still have two different controls (a SashForm and a TreeViewer's control), depending on the content to be displayed. In getControl(), I return the appropriate control but I still have the problem that the outline view's content is only updated when I switch forth and back between editors.

Comment: Added a bit about the controls